# Teradata JDBC Create Volatile Table error 3585

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, teradata

I have never used the Teradata JDBC driver before, so I may be running into something very obvious...

Basically, I am trying to create a volatile table from which I can query.

**Questions**

1. Maybe I just can't run `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE` statements like this...  What am I doing wrong?
2. Maybe the driver version is too old? (Currently 12.00.00.110)

**Java code**

```
PreparedStatement  pstmtCreateVT = dbConn.prepareStatement(util.getQuery("CREATE_VOLATILE_TABLE_ABC"));
   pstmtCreateVT.setInt(1, 7);
   pstmtCreateVT.setInt(2, 11);
   pstmtCreateVT.executeQuery();
```

**Query.properties**

```
CREATE_VOLATILE_TABLE_ABC = \
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE ABC \
AS ( SELECT DISTINCT t1.NAME \
  , lookup.price \
FROM SUPERMARKET.FRUITS t1 \
  INNER JOIN SUPERMARKET.PRICING lookup \
    ON 
      lookup.price BETWEEN ? AND ? \
) \
WITH DATA NO PRIMARY INDEX \
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

**Error**

```
2013-11-15 09:55:19,220 DEBUG [CreatePoolingConnection.createConnection:102] url: jdbc:teradata://<<some_url_here>>/DATABASE=SUPERMARKET,ENCRYPTDATA=ON,TMODE=ANSI
2013-11-15 09:55:19,673 ERROR [BOMPartsApplicability.fetch:245] ERROR:
com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 12.00.00.110] [Error 3585] [SQLState HY000] USING modifier NOT allowed with DDL.
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:277)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:102)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:285)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:176)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:108)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:99)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.Statement.executeStatement(Statement.java:309)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.Statement.prepareRequest(Statement.java:467)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:53)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.createPreparedStatement(TDSession.java:506)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalPreparedStatement.<init>(TeraLocalPreparedStatement.java:84)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.prepareStatement(TeraLocalConnection.java:328)
   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.prepareStatement(TeraLocalConnection.java:149)
   at GroceryStore.SetupFruits.fetch(BOMPartsApplicability.java:147)
   at GroceryStore.SetupFruits.main(BOMPartsApplicability.java:359)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can execute a DDL statement with placeholders?

Comment: Good call (I knew I was doing something dumb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you cannot specify placeholders for DDL statements if you want to execute them with `PreparedStatement` (I've just recreated your problem trying to create a simple table with a placeholder in the DDL).

Comment: Yes, I was able to run the query by taking out the placeholders and  changing to `executeUpdate()`. Maybe it doesn't make sense to use `PreparedStatement` in this case?

Comment: @user1766760 It depends really on what you need. If you are sure that injection attack is not possible in your case, you could just concatenate the parameters to your query (in general, not a good approach).

Comment: I was so used to using placeholders, didn't realize I can't use it in DDL statements.  But it seems string concatenation is unavoidable then (if I don't use something like a stored proc).

Comment: @user1766760 Unfortunately, even if you used stored procedure, you would still have to concatenate the parameters into the query... `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` wouldn't allow you to use placeholders there, just as it is not possible from Java. I've just checked it, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` wouldn't let me use placeholders either.

Comment: I know it's an old topic but in this case I would suggest creating first the volatile table with "NO DATA" and a fixed parameter and then (on the same connection) do the insert/select into the volatile.